# ZF2 I would like to pass json string

Tags: zend-framework2

I would like to pass json to action, something similar to passing simple variable:
/** module.config.php

```
'mobileapplication-topup' => array(
            'type'    => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/mob/topup[/:voucherID]',                    
                'constraints' => array(
                    'voucherID'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Mob\Controller\Topup',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
```

and TopupController.php

```
  public function indexAction()
{   

    echo ($this->params('voucherID'));

        $result = new ViewModel();
        $result->setTerminal(true);
        return $result;
    }


//** no layout //

    $response = $this->getResponse();
    $response->setStatusCode(200);        
    $response->setContent("Error");        
    return $response;
}
```

something similar to this, but just a json string instead of voucherID. What kind of constraints should be added to this json variable?

** Is there any way how to POST the form from other domain to ZF2?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to pass JSON *to* your action, or have the action *return* JSON (or both)? Either way, you really don't want JSON in the URL, so this isn't something you should be solving in the routes.

Comment: @TimFountain Yes I want to pass Json to my action. That's why I'm asking is there any way how to do that.

Comment: pass it in a POST field, get it in the controller with $this->getRequest()->getPost();

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution, but I don't think it is a perfect one...
What I was thinking that there is some way of passing variables using route

```
mvc.com/controller/param1/param2
```

and into this for example just pass a json and decode it in one of the controllers...
but at the moment I'm using basing _GET method

```
mvc.com/controller/param1/param2?"Json"={"p1":"value1","p2":"value2"}
```